# my on click function is not working in ursina

Tags: python, ursina

I don't know how to do that when the user clicks on Settings so that everything is invisible.  I tried

```
Play.on_click = Settings.visible = False
Play.on_click = quit.visible = False
Play.on_click = Play.visible = False
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: How are `Play`, `Settings` and `quit` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on_click` expects a function but you assigned a value. Try this instead:

```
def play_onclick():
    Settings.visible = False
    quit.visible = False
    Play.visible = False

Play.on_click = play_onclick # without parentheses!
```

Also, I'm assuming that `Play` is a `ursina.Button` instance. If that's the case, you should follow the Python naming convention of having its name start with a lowercase letter, i.e. `play`.